# if a user has read access to a file, can a group deny that right?

Tags: linux, permissions

in linux,

if a user belongs to 2 groups.
1 group gives the user access to a file (say read)
the other group doesn't allow them access.

Is there a way to deny access to a file EVEN if a group the user belongs to is giving him read access?

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this would be to create two groups, one which said user is a member of, and one which that user isn't, and assign the groups accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Last I knew this wasn't possible.

If the user shouldn't have access, then the user shouldn't belong to that group / role or the group / role shouldn't have access.

Answer (score 0):

File permissions have only **one** group-id field. Which means the file can be accessed if the user belongs to that group. Other belongings do not affect it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with built-in Linux permissions.

[POSIX ACL](http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/), on Linux, doesn't allow this either.